# number of combinations for 5x5 matrix where up to one cell in each row and column can be selected

Tags: matrices, permutations

If I have a 5 x 5 matrix, how many different combinations are there if up to one cell in each row and column can  be selected and how do I work this out, i.e. at most 5 selected cells without collision in row or column?

For example,

```
[ x, 0, 0, 0, 0
  0, x, 0, 0, 0
  0, 0, x, 0, 0
  0, 0, 0, x, 0
  0, 0, 0, 0, x]
```

is one option

but it could easily be

```
[ x, 0, 0, 0, 0
  0, x, 0, 0, 0
  0, 0, x, 0, 0
  0, 0, 0, x, 0
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

[ x, x, 0, 0, 0
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0
  0, 0, x, 0, 0
  0, 0, 0, x, 0
  0, 0, 0, 0, x]
```

is not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you place $k$ ones, you can choose rows in $\binom5k$ ways, choose columns in $\binom5k$ ways, and assign them to each other in $k!$ ways, so the total number of options is

$$
\sum_{k=0}^5\binom5k^2k!=5!^2\sum_{k=0}^5\frac1{k!(5-k)!^2}=1546
$$

([Wolfram|Alpha computation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5!%5E2%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5E5%5Cfrac1%7Bk!(5-k)!%5E2%7D&dataset=)).

Comment: This sounds about right, trying to produce test cases for a product I'm building and I couldn't seem to prove that there are too many. Thanks!